# How to fix specific weight at embedding layer

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to implement cnn sentence classification and padding 0 for variation length sentences.

But it is not reasonalble for this task because 0 will be treated as a vocabulary.

To solve this problem, I want to fix weight all zero for 0 map to word-vector in embedding layer,and other vocabular still can be trained.

Reference paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5882

Following is my current code:

```py
w2v_weight = np.array(list(data['id_vec'].values()))
# add zeros in first dim:
zero = np.zeros((1,w2v_weight.shape[1]))
w2v_weight = np.concatenate((zero,w2v_weight),axis=0) 

embedding_layer = Embedding(len(data["word_id"]) + 1, 300, weights= [w2v_weight],
                        input_length=data['x_test'].shape[1], trainable=True)

embedding_layer2 = Embedding(len(data["word_id"]) + 1, 300, weights= [w2v_weight],
                        input_length=data['x_test'].shape[1], trainable=False)

model_input = Input(shape=(None,),dtype='int32')

embedded_sequences2 = embedding_layer2(model_input)
embedded_sequences1 = embedding_layer(model_input)
ebd_cct = Concatenate()([embedded_sequences1,embedded_sequences2])

conv1 = Convolution1D(filters=100,kernel_size = 3,padding="same")(ebd_cct)
conv2 = Convolution1D(filters=100,kernel_size = 4,padding="same")(ebd_cct)
conv3 = Convolution1D(filters=100,kernel_size = 5,padding="same")(ebd_cct)
conv_a = Concatenate()([conv1,conv2,conv3])
conv_a = Activation("relu")(conv_a)
conv_add = GlobalMaxPool1D()(conv_a) 
z = Dropout(0.5)(conv_add) 

model_output = Dense(4, activation="softmax",kernel_constraint = max_norm(3.))(z)
model_1_two = Model(model_input, model_output)

model_1_two.summary()

model_1_two.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="Adadelta",         
metrics=['acc'])
history_1_two = model_1_two.fit(data["x_train"], data["y_train"],shuffle=True,
      callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor="val_acc",patience=50)],
      batch_size=50, epochs=20000,validation_data=(data["x_test"], data["y_test"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code I assume you're using Keras. Then, you can define the use of `0` as the out-of-vocabulary (OOV) index by setting `mask_zero` to `True`:

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(len(data["word_id"]) + 1, 300, weights= [w2v_weight],
                            input_length=data['x_test'].shape[1], trainable=True,
                            mask_zero=True)
```

For more information, see the [documentation for `Embedding()`](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/).

Comment: Tks, I had tried, but conv1d layer doesn't support mask_zero

Comment: Why do you need to mask the zeros in the convolutional layer?

Comment: I had not  mask the zeros in the convolutional layer,
I  mask the zeros in the embedding layer.
but Conv1D doesn't sopport it,
when use mask_zero,
following layer must support it all

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! Are you sure that you need to mask out the OOV words? Naively I would assume that even if you get an "OOV" embedding output, that feature would be completely irrelevant to your task and hence would be "ignored" in the convolutional layers.

Comment: I think we have to try two ways to determine which one is better.